# C# REST API Controller: same route with 2 different actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, owin

When using the following routes:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "new_device",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/devices",
            defaults: new { controller = "Devices", action = "new_device" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "devices_list",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/devices",
            defaults: new { controller = "Devices", action = "devices_list", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
        );
```

The controller looks as follows:

```
public class DevicesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IHttpActionResult))]
    [Route("api/v1/devices")]
    [ActionName("new_device")]
    [ValidateModel]
    public IHttpActionResult NewDevice([System.Web.Http.FromBody] Device device )
    {
         ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IHttpActionResult))]
    [Route("api/v1/devices")]
    [ActionName("devices_list")]
    [ValidateModel]
    public List<Device> GetAllDevices()
    {
        ...
    }
```

My expectation would be that the router would find the correct route based on the HttpMethod used since even it's using the same URI it is using a different HttpMethod.

But instead it fails with the following:

> > "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."

My guess is because it fins a match with the URI and then checks if the method if the same.

Is there a way to achieve using the same URI with different Http Method which is by the way REST guidelines? Am I missing something?

Comment: You have a custom `ActionName`, and `Route`, I'm not sure what that's going to do, but probably not what you want.  Try removing the `ActionName` attribute.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api#routing-variations

Comment: Why is it a problem to have both a route and action?

Comment: 1) You don't need to specify an entry in Route config and attribute routes--pick one or the other. 2) There's really no difference in your route structure in Route config. That means one of those, the latter, is useless. A route in Route config effectively defines the structure of the URL you expect to receive. 3) What are you entering as your URL?

Comment: Use `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`

Comment: I don't know that it's a problem, but the different `ActionName`s means those 2 methods do not have the same route.

Comment: Adding config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() did the trick. Thx @JessedeWit

Answer (score 2):

Ok , I check your whole code. I think you are trying to achieve the calls in complicated way.

Following code is for the configuration :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

and follwoing is your controller code :

```
public class DevicesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IHttpActionResult))]       
    [ActionName("newDevice")]

    public IHttpActionResult NewDevice([System.Web.Http.FromBody] Device device)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IHttpActionResult))]        
    [ActionName("devices_list")]

    public List<Device> GetAllDevices()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I removed ValidateModel. I think it's your custom attribute or somehow related with built in nuget package.

Anyways, execute the calls with Postman or any HTTP client tool. It should work , as it was working at my end with above mentioned code.

**Example Calls:**

> https://localhost:44370/api/v1/devices/devices_list  = > Get. 
>   https://localhost:44370/api/v1/devices/newDevice  => Post. *Provide body as post call for the object.*

Comment: OP has already resolved the issue before your answer, please see comments below the question